# Change size of all bar buttons based on the current device

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

In my app I want to change the size of all bar buttons in all viewControllers that I have.The entry point viewController is embed in navigation controller and I have navigation bar in all of my viewControllers.I tried(programmatically) to change them by making outlets from them and then changing the size but then understood that it has to be a simpler way of doing it. I know how to check what is the current device but don't know how to implement the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at UIAppearance class for your needs.